# libvrtd: host interface gets an IP when using macvtap on virtual machine

Tags: linux, networking, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I'm using a 2nd ethernet adapter for the WAN of my virtual OPNsense installation in KVM/QEMU.

All works good, but I noticed that the KVM host itself also gets an IP address and has routes installed for it.
I only want the virtual OPNsense interface to have an IP, not the host interface.

The interface on the KVM host looks like this:

```
enx3c18a0057e95: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet 178.119.13.164  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 178.119.15.255
        inet6 fe80::3e18:a0ff:fe05:7e95  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a02:181f:0:6061:4016:4dfa:8cbc:23b3  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 3c:18:a0:05:7e:95  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4255467  bytes 5047527392 (4.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2983482  bytes 829553375 (791.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

but in /etc/network/interfaces there is no IP configured:

```
auto enx3c18a0057e95
iface enx3c18a0057e95 inet manual
```

Also there is no dhclient running.

Strangely, all the other vnet, macvtap and virbr also have APIPA 169.254.X.X addresses.
(see route table below)

Some more details:

```
root@svr:~# for vm in $(virsh list | grep running | awk '{print $2}'); do echo "$vm: " && virsh dumpxml $vm | grep  "vnet" ; done
debian-vpn:
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <target dev='vnet1'/>
OPNsense:
      <target dev='vnet2'/>
      <target dev='vnet3'/>
root@svr:~# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.26a83932e330   no      eno1
                            vnet0
                            vnet2
virbr2      8000.525400315d13   yes     vnet1
                            vnet3
root@svr:~# ps aux | grep dhc
nobody      1298  0.0  0.0  11572  2276 ?        S    16:19   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/VPN.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper

root@svr:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0 onlink
10.18.197.4/30 dev tap1 proto kernel scope link src 10.18.197.5
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.185.141
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1.134 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.62.148
169.254.0.0/16 dev vnet1 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.77.229
169.254.0.0/16 dev vnet0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.133.164
169.254.0.0/16 dev macvtap0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.122.85
169.254.0.0/16 dev macvtap1 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.222.208
169.254.0.0/16 dev vnet3 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.174.42
169.254.0.0/16 dev vnet2 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.219.41
169.254.0.0/16 dev tap1 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.149.40
178.119.0.0/20 dev enx3c18a0057e95 proto kernel scope link src 178.119.13.164
178.119.0.1 dev enx3c18a0057e95 scope link
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.7
192.168.101.0/24 dev virbr2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.101.1
195.130.130.5 via 178.119.0.1 dev enx3c18a0057e95
195.130.131.5 via 178.119.0.1 dev enx3c18a0057e95
```

the last entries in the routing table are DNS server it somehow picked up via DHCP.

How to prevent the interfaces getting an IP address on the host and only have it on the virtual machine?

thanks

Comment: I noticed only when starting the virtual machines, the host interfaces get an IP. Before it's just the interface up without IP.

Answer (score 0):

After searching, disabling dnsmasq, dhclient, .....
Turns out that connmand was running

Uninstalled connman and all the host interfaces look normal and don't have an IP anymore.